# Get All But The Last Element - JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on a function that returns an array containing all but the last element of the array located at the given key.

-If the array is empty, it should return an empty array.
-If the property at the given key is not an array, it return an empty array.
-If there is no property at the key, it should return an empty array.

Here's my codes:

```
function getAllButLastElementOfProperty(obj, key) {
  var output = [];

   if ( key in obj && Array.isArray(obj[key]) && obj[key].length !== 0)
  {
        for(var i = 0; i < obj[key].length; i++ ){
          if(obj[key].length - 1){
              output.push(obj[key][i]);
          }

        }
       return output;
  }
}


var obj = {
  key: [1, 2, 3]
};
var output = getAllButLastElementOfProperty(obj, 'key');
console.log(output); // --> MUST RETURN [1,2]
```

My codes returns [1,2,3].

ANy idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you messed up the -1... try to use it in the for loop not in the if statement... :D

Comment: `if(obj[key].length - 1){` always returns true (except for 0), so probably the mistake is there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optimized `getAllButLastElementOfProperty` function version:

```js
function getAllButLastElementOfProperty(obj, k) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(k) || !Array.isArray(obj[k]) || obj[k].length === 0) {
        return [];
    }
    return obj[k].slice(0, -1);  // getting all but the last element of the array
}

var obj = { key: [1, 2, 3] },
    output = getAllButLastElementOfProperty(obj, 'key');
    
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could generalize your function by making it take an array as an argument and then calling `getAllButLastElement(obj.key)`. This also returns an empty array if the object does not have the property `key`.

This could then be implemented like this:

```js
function getAllButLastElement(arr) {
  if(!Array.isArray(arr))
    return []; // Return an empty array

  return arr.slice(0, -1);
}

let obj = {
  'key': [ 1, 2, 3 ],
  'empty': [ ]
};

console.log('obj.key:', getAllButLastElement(obj.key)); // Proper Array
console.log('obj.empty:', getAllButLastElement(obj.empty)); // Empty Array
console.log('obj.unknown:', getAllButLastElement(obj.unkown)); // Property does not exist
```

Passing a negative number to `Array.prototype.slice` accesses the array from the end. In the snippet this means that we take everything from the first element up to the index `arr.length - 1`. If we were to use `arr.slice(-1)` this would *only* return the last element (still as an array of course) which is the exact opposite of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this condition for your `if` statement

```
if(i !== obj[key].length - 1){
          output.push(obj[key][i]);
      }
```